# git contributors not showing up properly in github/etc

Tags: git, github

I'm working in a team on a big project, but when I'm doing the merges I'd like the developers name to appear in github as the author -- currently, I'm the only one showing up since I'm merging.

**Context:**

There are 4 developers, and we're using the "integration manager" workflow using GitHub. Our "blessed" repo is under the organization, and each developer manages their pub/private repo. I've been tasked with being the integration manager, so I'm doing the merges, etc.

Where I could be messing up is that I'm basically working out of my rob/project.git instead of the org/project.git -- so when I do local merges I operate on *my* repo then I push to both my public and the org public. (Make sense?) When I push to the blessed repo nobody else shows up as an author, since all commits are coming from me -- how can I get around this?

--

Also, we all forked org/project.git, yet in the network graph nobody is showing up -- did we mess this up too? I'm used to working with git solo and don't have too much experience with handling a team of devs. Merging seems like the right thing to do, but I'm being thrown off since GitHub is kind of ignoring the other contributors.

If this makes no sense at all, how do you use GitHub to manage a single project across 4 developers? (preferably the integration mgr workflow, branching i think would solve the problem)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be pulling from the a nonexistent config or wrong config

You can check your config list like this and debug from there:
git config --list

When you are working on Rob's repo you could use repository specfic configs.
The .git/config file in each repository is used to store the configuration for that repository, and $HOME/.gitconfig is used to store a per-user configuration as fallback values for the .git/config file. The file /etc/gitconfig can be used to store a system-wide default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your project locally, e.g. using `gitk --all`, do you see the names you expect? If so, then it's just the way github displays the committer rather than the author. Sourceforge also does that so.